# Adding analysis comments programatically to a load test rather than through the load test editor

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, load-testing

I am trying to add analysis comments to my load test runs so that I can distinguish different load test runs. I understand you can add analysis comments to a running load test by using the VS Load Test Editor ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404677.aspx#Notes)) but I am looking to add an analysis note programatically. Can I do this in a load test plugin? I am running load tests using the mstest.exe command in a powershell script across distributed systems and cannot manually add these comments as they run.

Multiple concurrent load tests are being run on the same agents and against different endpoints, with the results being stored in a central SQL server. There's no way to distinguish load test results by which build definition kicks off the load test (the agent is being deployed as well through the build definition).

Is there a way to do this without editing the .loadtest XML file to update maybe the run settings with a unique name that I can then query my SQL server on?

Comment: try reflection to access you test